# Регулярное выражение ограничение по набору слов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется тексты вида:

```
keyOne: "Lorem ipsum"
keyTwo: "Lorem ipsum"
```

и:

```
keyOne: "Lorem ipsum"
"dolor \"sit amet\", "
"consectetur adipiscing elit"
keyTwo: "Lorem ipsum"
```

Если в первом случае получить пару «ключ: значение» легко можно по признаку `\/"$\`, то во втором случае выход только один — искать совпадение с одним из ключей (фиксированный ограниченный набор). Вопрос такой, каким образом правильно добавить ограничение на вхождение ключей в шаблон `\(?<key>(keyOne|keyTwo))[\s*](?<value>[\"][[:print:]\s]*[\"]$)?\`, чтобы получить во втором случае значение ключа `keyOne`:

```
"Lorem ipsum"
"dolor sit amet, "
"consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему признака начала строки перед ключом и факта, что значения целиком заключены в кавычки более чем достаточно.

```
/(?<key>^\w+):\s*(?<value>"(?:[^"]+|"\n")+")/gm
```

Пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ekHjqm/1/)

Если перечисление ключей вам необходимо из каких то других соображений, то можете их вписать прямо в группу `<key>`, вместо `\w`.

С учетом возможного экранирования кавычек обратными косыми и экранирования самих обратных косых, по правилам большинства языков программирования, выходит следующее:

```
/(?<key>^\w+):\s*(?<value>"(?:[^"\\]+|\\.|"\n")+")/gm
```

Привет на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LqIiNR/3/)

Comment: Да, это хороший вариант, и он абсолютно правильно работает, но в кавычках (я не привел пример) могут быть любые значения, в том числе экранирование кавычки (\") и в этом случае надо добавить проверку на слеш перед кавычкой

Comment: @Alaksander Поэтому всегда максимально точно описывайте задачу. Можете дописать про экранирование. А я пока вспомню как оно обычно реализуется. (Я же правильно понимаю что `\\"` надо воспринимать именно как нормальную косую и закрывающуюся кавычку)

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно, спасибо за уделенное время